# Error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory, opencv, python-tesseract

I am new to OCR and Tesseract. As per my assignment, I have to solve a task where I have to extract the text from a figure. But, I am getting this error which I don't know how to solve. Any help will be appreciated!

The error code:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
```

The original code:

```
!pip install pytesseract
!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import numpy as np


image_path = Image.open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/cropped1.jpg")
image_path = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image_path), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2_imshow(image_path)
extractedInformation = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image_path))
```

Comment: `image_path` is an array, return by the first `cv2.cvtColor`. Then, you open the *image*, instead of a file pointer. Basically, you're doing `Image.open(cv2.cvtColor(np.array(Image.open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/cropped1.jpg"))))`. See the problem there?

Comment: Just don't assign to `image_path` if it's *not* a file path. Just a differently named variable.